# clearing an array in preparation for new array values

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, strtok

The function gets an input from the user using read() and breaks it down using strtok and places it into an array. The program loops until it reaches an error (which i won't get into because that isn't the problem here) or if the program is terminated by the user. However, when it loops back around and reads the input from the user, it seems to be hanging onto the previous input from the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    argc++;

    char buf[BUFFERSIZE];
    int n;
        printf("Please enter commands: \n");

    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0)
        {
        printf("original string: %s:\n", buf);
        buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
        printf("after change: %s:\n", buf);
    
        int i = 0;

        char* array[100];
        char* token1 = strtok(buf, " ");

        while ((token1 != NULL))
        {
            array[i++] = token1;
            token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }//while

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
            printf("Array value %d: %s:\n", j, array[j]);
        }//for
        
        if (buf == "exit")
        {
            printf("found it\n");
        }//if

        
            for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
            {
            pid_t pid;
            
            if (argc >= 1) 
            {
                if ((pid = fork()) < 0) 
                {
                    perror("fork");
                }//if
                else if (pid == 0) 
                { // child process
                    if (execvp(array[0], array) == -1) 
                    {
                        perror("execvp");
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    } // if
                }//else if
                else 
                {   // parent process
                    int status;
                    wait(&status);
                    printf("Please enter commands again: \n");
                    
                }//else     
            }//if
            else 
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Please specify the name of the program to exec as a command line argument\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }//if
        }//for
    }//while
    if (n == -1) perror("read");
}//main
```

I've tried to clear the array and clear "buf" but no luck. i have a feeling it has to do with the read() and the fact that "buf" is hanging onto its old value.

Comment: `if (buf == "exit")` is _not_ the way to compare strings in C. It only compares the _addresses_ of the strings [_not_ their contents], and here, it will _never_ be a match. You want: `if (strcmp(buf,"exit") == 0)`

Comment: @CraigEstey okay, thank you. That was another part of the program that I was gonna fix later but thank you for helping with me that ahead of time

Comment: It might be better to use (e.g.) `fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)` instead of `read(0,buf,sizeof(buf))`. With `read`, you can't guarantee that the buffer ends in `\n` [as you'd like]. If the user inputs (e.g.) `hello world\ngoodbye galaxy\n`, `read` might return a sequence of: `hell`, `o wor`, `ld\n`, `good`, `bye galaxy\n` across 5 read calls

Comment: @CraigEstey Thats a good point but the point of the project is to be low-level io. and it will only be running single-line commands. i just need help with my current problem

Comment: If you use `read`, you have to account for the possible split up of the line text across multiple `read` calls. That is, join/split manually to get a single whole buffer equivalent to what `fgets` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefaced by my top comments ...

1. `read` does not add 0x00 the way `fgets` does, so we have to do it manually.
2. `execvp` needs the array to be terminated with a `NULL` entry.
3. child should use `exit` instead of `return`.

---

Here's the refactored code. It is annotated. Note that this code does *not* do the split/join of the buffer to guarantee the buffer ending in newline as suggested by my top comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    argc++;

    char buf[BUFFERSIZE];
    int n;

    printf("Please enter commands: \n");

// NOTE/BUG: read does _not_ add 0x00 the way fgets does
#if 0
    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
#else
    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFERSIZE - 1)) > 0) {
        buf[n] = 0;
#endif
        printf("original string: %s:\n", buf);
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("after change: %s:\n", buf);

        int i = 0;

        char *array[100];
        char *token1 = strtok(buf, " ");

        while ((token1 != NULL)) {
            array[i++] = token1;
            token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

// NOTE/BUG: execvp needs a NULL terminator
#if 1
        array[i] = NULL;
#endif

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("Array value %d: %s:\n", j, array[j]);
        }

// NOTE/BUG: wrong way to compare strings
#if 0
        if (buf == "exit")
#else
        if (strcmp(buf, "exit") == 0) {
            printf("found it\n");
            break;
        }
#endif

        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            pid_t pid;

            if (argc >= 1) {
                if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
                    perror("fork");
                }

                // child process
                else if (pid == 0) {
                    if (execvp(array[0], array) == -1) {
                        perror("execvp");
#if 0
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
#else
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
#endif
                    }
                }

                // parent process
                else {
                    int status;

                    wait(&status);
                    printf("Please enter commands again: \n");
                }
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Please specify the name of the program to exec as a command line argument\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }
    if (n == -1)
        perror("read");
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`